# Flutter Integrated Tests like Native "AndroidTest" tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In Android Native development, I created integrated tests that test my database access and services. I used "@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)" to run my tests on the simulator without any UI involvement. I mean tests under the "androidTest" folder.

I am trying to port my tests to Flutter. I tried unit, widget, and integration tests but no one allowed me to integrate test my code as on Android. Is there is any way to do the same on Flutter?

Comment: You need to `flutter run` your unit tests instead of `flutter test` if the tests include access to native platform like plugins do.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flutter run your unit tests instead of flutter test if the tests include access to native platform like plugins do.